# Is it possible to use all the CPUs of a node with Slurm?

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu, slurm

I use a R function which is not parallelizable (it only uses one CPU of a node). I use several nodes to split the computations I need to do : so, the function is used on several nodes, but only one CPU is used. Each node has 32 CPUs. For the moment, if I use 10 nodes, I would like to know if it could be possible to split these 10 jobs on only one node, and each job will use 1 CPU?

I mean : from 10 jobs on 10 nodes with 1 CPU/node, change this strategy to get these 10 jobs on one node, with 10 CPUs used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A script similar to this should work (assuming here that you use bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J JOB_NAME # job name
#SBATCH -N 1  # 1 Node cores/node)
#SBATCH -n 10 # 10 tasks

./job1 &
./job2 &
./job3 &
# ...
```

This will reserve 1 node with 10 tasks and run the jobs in parallel. Depending on the environment you're working on, you may need to call some wrapper tool to run the binaries (and set affinity, if required).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the memory usage of your job you can submit something like this several times:

```
!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --share
#SBATCH --mem=2000  # max. memory in MB
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1

./script_to_run
```

The option `--share` tells the job allocation to share resources with other running jobs when it is allowed by the partitions shared option, see the sbatch man pages for details:

> The default shared behavior depends on system configuration and the partition's Shared option takes precedence over the job's option.

If sharing is allowed by the partition settings the jobs will be submitted to a single node until either memory or CPU max out.